# Which of these files is the signed apk

Tags: apk, visual-studio-cordova

Here i'm again with a last doubt.
I've signed my apk (cordova) using visual studio 2015 .

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

But inside my release folder i've found many files.

Which of these files is the signed apk to upload on store? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that you have selected (namely, MainActivity-release.apk) should be the signed package with your release key!

Glad, that it was simple resolution to your issue and you could get a signed APK for your project. Let us know if you have any more questions!

Subhag Oak.